# Combine Observable with second Observable which uses results from from the first one

Tags: java, rxjs, rx-java, rx-android

I have two methods returning Observable:

```
Observable<String> firstObservable();
Observable<String> secondObservable(String value);
```

For each result from the first Observable I get new instance of the second Observable. For each result from the second observable I would return object with combined results.

```
firstObservable ->  x----x----x----x----x
                     \    \    \    \    \
secondObservable ->   y(x)-y(x)-y(x)-y(x)-y(x)
                      \     \     \     \     \
result ->             {x,y}-{x,y}-{x,y}-{x,y}-{x,y}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an overloaded variant of `flatMap`, the second argument of which is the combining function that has access to the initial item and the one produced by the second observable:

`firstObservable.flatMap(string -> secondObservable(string), (s, s2) -> s + s2);`

Comment: Thanks! I was know about flatMap but somehow haven't noticed this overload.

Comment: I think that usage is deprecated now?

Comment: @ahong this answer was given in the RxJava 2 days. To be honest, I don't know if it's any different in RxJava 3. But it doesn't look deprecated in RxJava 2 at least.

Comment: Um.. sorry I was confused. Thought this was a RxJs solution--it is deprecated in RxJs I think, but not sure if the interface is the same or not between languages.