# RxJava and Retrofit - Chain service response

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

New to `RxJava`. Trying to achieve something trivial but can't seem to wrap my head around the entire `RxJava` paradigm so far. All i want is to make two service calls one after the other and simply return a final custom `POJO` consisting of the response of the two calls. Point to be noted here is that the two calls are independent of each other. Only if the first calls comes back with a success, the second one should fire. The second one does not use any data from the first service call. What i have so far.

```
 RestWebClient.get().getFirstImage()
                .flatMap(firstImage -> RestWebClient.get().getSecondImage())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(firstImage -> mainFragmentPresenterInterface.showImages(firstImage));
```

1. I am not sure how can i chain the response of two separate network calls and return them as a single POJO back to the presenter.
2. Also how can we make sure that getSecondImage() is called only if getFirstImage() was a success?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started off correctly, I'll just modify your snippet a little:

```java
RestWebClient.get().getFirstImage()
        .flatMap(firstImage -> /* first image success */ ? RestWebClient.get().getSecondImage() : Observable.just(null),
                (firstImage, secondImage) -> Pair.create(firstImage, secondImage))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(imagePair -> mainFragmentPresenterInterface.showImages(imagePair));
```

Comment: do you mind elaborating on the flatmap line..? How can we determine if the first image was a success

Comment: @user2511882 I just used an overloaded variant of `flatMap` that gives you access to the first image after executing the `flatMap` conversion. I don't know what `getFirstImage()` returns, so it's not up to me to say how to determine if it was a success or not.

Comment: ok however there is the comment of the /*first image success*/..how do we determine that since there is no oncomplete, onerror etc implemented here.. Also what is the ternary operation used here in context for. I am new to RxJava. So that whole flatmap line is beyond me right now. If you can elaborate it a bit more in the answer that would be great.

Comment: The `getFirstImage()` returns an observable.. `Observable<FirstImage> getFirstImage`

Comment: @user2511882 what does this observable emit when the first image fetching was unsuccessful? Emits a `null` object, throws an exception, doesn't emit anything, returns a `ResponseBody` object from okhttp with a response code?

Comment: Its returns a JSON object with the status code and the reason.

Comment: @user2511882 so this is what you can use for the `/* first image success */` part, right? The `flatMap` question is not new, [here's something similar to your case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35292875/4096987), I think.

Comment: of course i can. Just glossed over it for some reason. One last question, why are we doing a `Observable.just(null)` in case if the firstImage fails? Shouldn't we just cancel the subscription at that point? Also where is the imagePair coming from.

Comment: @user2511882 We cannot really cancel it. As an alternative you can expand the single line lambda and do `throw new IllegalStateException()` in the `else` branch. In theory this exception should fall through to `subscribe()` where you intercept it. But as you can see, it's more verbose and obscure.